# Grails global config/dependency resolution

Tags: grails

I'm behind a firewall that doesn't allow me to download from grailsCentral or mavenCentral. But there is one specific public maven repository that IT lets me download from (say 'repo.maven.apache.org'). Is there a way to configure grails with a global configuration? Or more specifically to use a repository globally?

Excerpt from BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  inherits 'global'
  log 'warn'

  repositories {
    grailsCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo 'http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases'

    // Normally I would add this line to every project
    //mavenRepo 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/'
  }
...
```

Is there a way that I can create a file like `~/.grails/BuildConfig.groovy` that has content like the following?

```
grails.global.dependency.resolution = {
  repositories {
    mavenRepo 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/'
  }
}
```

Then this repo would be used for every project.:)

Comment: do you have a proxy server to use to get to grailscentral etc? This can be configured in .grails/ProxySettings.groovy; Otherwise did you try setting dependency resolution in .grails/settings.groovy?

Comment: I am able to tunnel with an ssh server to create a local proxyserver, but it isn't always connected. I'll look into .grails/settings.groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this using the method posted by @ak-tech (Thank you!)

in ~/.grails/settings.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
  repositories {
    mavenRepo 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you change BuildConfig.groovy in {your-grails-installation-dir}\src\grails\grails-app\conf\BuildConfig.groovy the way you want, then every time you run

```
grails> create-app myApp
```

you should get the BuildConfig.groovy with the changes you want.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want. I essentially want to be able to have the configuration across all projects regardless of whether I created them or not. So if I check out a project from github, I use MY mirrors rather than the project's.